# Can different case teams in different territories have different holidays for calculating escalations, etc?

Tags: case, territory, holidays

I have a situation where client has different holiday lists for different territories. For example there are 2 territories T1 and T2, and there are 3 holidays H1, H2 and H3. Is it possible to assign holiday H1 to T1, H2 to T2 and H3 to both T1 and T2?

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved by using Business Hours (one BH record for each territory) and then associating a different set of holidays for each business hours record.
Then use the standard lookup from Case to Business Hours, and the holidays will be associated to that Case.

All standard features requiring zero code.